# Why SQL INNER JOIN returns all records regardless of condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, foreach

I have two tables `users` and `test`. The `users` table contains the information about student and `test` table has its test details. I want to show all the details of test to the specific student after login according to his roll number. For achieving this, I have tried using following `foreach` function and `INNER JOIN` in the query.

```
<?php 
      foreach($conn->query('SELECT test.date, test.sub,test.topic,test.marks,test.rank FROM test JOIN users ON test.rollno=users.rollno order by date desc')as $row){ ?>
        <button class="accordion"><b>Test on <?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime( $row['date'] )); ?></b></button>
          <div class="panel">
           <p>
           <table border="1">
            <?php
            echo "<tr><td>Date: " . date('d-m-Y', strtotime( $row['date'] )) . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Subject: " . $row['sub'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Topic: " . $row['topic'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Marks: " . $row['marks'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Rank: " . $row['rank'] . "</td></tr>"; ?>
         </table>
            </p>
          </div>
      <?php }?>
```

This returns all the test records regardless of roll no. I have `rollno` column common in both table. I want the query to show records matching the current roll number. Please help.

Comment: `WHERE user.rollno = ?`?

Comment: first, print your query and run in the database

Comment: @KrunalPandya It worked using this query `SELECT test.date, test.sub,test.topic,test.marks,test.rank FROM test JOIN users USING(rollno)
WHERE rollno=12 order by date desc` but as it is `session` If I put `rollno=$userRow['rollno']` then It says syntax error

Comment: Can you print the roll no on the page, and then once you get that working, you can use that variable in the where clause

Comment: @variable I tried it. The `rollno` prints on page, but the error is `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$temp' in 'where clause'' in C:\wamp64\www\rathi-classes\home.php on line 367`

Comment: @variable here is what I've done `$temp=print($userRow['rollno']);
    foreach($conn->query('SELECT test.date, test.sub,test.topic,test.marks,test.rank FROM test JOIN users USING(rollno)
WHERE rollno=$temp order by date desc')as $row){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved by just changing the query as `SELECT test.date, test.sub,test.topic,test.marks,test.rank FROM test JOIN users USING(rollno) WHERE rollno='.$userRow['rollno'].' order by date desc` where, `$userRow['rollno']` is a session variable which contains the value of roll no. of currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood you want to select for one user but you don't filter on him:

```
SELECT test.date,
       test.sub,
       test.topic,
       test.marks,
       test.rank
FROM test
JOIN users USING(rollno)
WHERE rollno=yourusernumber
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: It worked using this query `SELECT test.date, test.sub,test.topic,test.marks,test.rank FROM test JOIN users USING(rollno)
WHERE rollno=12 order by date desc` but as it is `session` If I put `rollno=$userRow['rollno']` then It says syntax error

Comment: this is the error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '["rollno"] order by date desc' at line 2' in C:\wamp64\www\rathi-classes\home.php on line 366`

Comment: Again this appears below `PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '["rollno"] order by date desc' at line 2 in C:\wamp64\www\rathi-classes\home.php on line 366`